# Jquery load Umbraco macroscript cshtml page

Tags: jquery, umbraco

Am trying to load cshtml razor page when click on load button see code below:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $('span').text('loading...');
        $('span').load('/MacroScripts/Page02.cshtml');
    });
});
```

However am getting 403 (Forbidden) back from the jquery.

Site is using Umbraco and Razor pages but not MVC.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

I have done this before with umbraco 4.11.7 if you look at http://www.steinias.com/ the feed of news / events in the middle of the page comes from ajax call to a template that has that macro. So instead of calling the macro directly create template with that macro on and then call that template. In my case i created new template and allowed it on home page then called it so im making ajax call to http://www.steinias.com/HomeBoxAjaxLoader

Regards

Ismail

Answer (score 0):

Calling a macroscript directly is not a good option in Umbraco!

You need to create a macro containing your macroscript then put it in a template (winforms) or relate it to your document (MVC) then call that page with something like : 
/parentNode/Page02.aspx